# How to make a score from multiples KPIs

Tags: statistics, kpi, risk-analysis

I am wondering if is it possible to create a *global* score using multiple KPIs with different scales.

Example:

[image]

I would like to join all this KPIs in one score that could tell me what version is better. Is it possible?  (I consider the 3 with the same weight in the score)

Comment: Are you looking for a formula to normalize all the 3 KPIs into one global value or for a tool that would do that?

Comment: Looking for a formula and understand the procedure of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite some theory on (credit) rating methods which provides a profound mathematical base for what you are after. You might start reading about [score cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_scorecards) in general. An abundant way of combining different scores uses [Logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

The short answer to your question: There is no single best way to combine three KPIs, you have to try different formulas, and decide on one of the formulas based on some statistics tests in a validation step.

#### Further reading

- [Using a Balanced Scorecard to Measure Your Key Performance Indicators](https://www.pcg-services.com/using-a-balanced-scorecard-to-measure-your-key-performance-indicators/) -  a brief primer on the topic
- [Chapter on Logit](https://books.google.de/books?id=C8mxdgm_K8EC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=logit+rating&source=bl&ots=nHXueXJ1CZ&sig=ACfU3U2eK-wtQ-pehUXkII0W1LFd_kA_ZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrwYShntbpAhXIDewKHWa1D_AQ6AEwDXoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=logit%20rating&f=false) from the book Stefan Trueck, Svetlozar T. Rachev: *Rating Based Modeling of Credit Risk: Theory and Application of Migration*
- [Guidelines on Credit Risk Management - OeNB as PDF](https://www.oenb.at/dam/jcr:1db13877-21a0-40f8-b46c-d8448f162794/rating_models_tcm16-22933.pdf)